# How do I put a regular expression into a get statement in Cypress?

Tags: regex, testing, cypress

I need to use a regular expression to get an element in Cypress.

Regex:

```js
/\[data-test-id="table-element-[0-9]-[0-9]:[0-9]-cell"\]/gm
```

I need in to use it in the following Cypress statement

```js
cy.get(/\[data-test-id="table-element-[0-9]-[0-9]:[0-9]-cell"\]/gm).click()
```

However, I am getting an error: `Argument of type 'RegExp' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An alternative to a regex might be to use a partial attribute match

```
cy.get('[data-test-id^="table-element-"])  // ^= means starts-with "table-element-"
```

or

```
cy.get('[data-test-id^="table-element-"][data-test-id$="-cell"]) // also ends with "-cell"
```

---

This uses a regex inside a jQuery filter (but I'm sure there's an easier way)

```
cy.get('[data-test-id]')
  .invoke('filter', function() {
    const matches = [...this.attributes].filter(attr => {
      attr.value.match(/table-element-[0-9]-[0-9]:[0-9]-cell/)
    })
    return matches
  })
  .should('have.length.gt', 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also assert the attribute with the regular expression something like this:

```
cy.get('td')
  .should('have.attr', 'data-test-id')
  .and('match', /\table-element-[0-9]-[0-9]:[0-9]-cell/gm)
  .click()
```

Comment: According to the documentation (https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/contains.html), contains is for finding text on the screen. In my case, I'm trying to find a data attribute in an element so I dont think contains will work here.

Comment: Wat kind of elements are these which has data-test-id? Since it has table mentioned are they td or tr or something else ?

Comment: Still doesn't seem to be working. I am clicking on button elements so I just changed the get statement to use button.

Comment: I think you have to edit the regex. This matches only the value of the `data-test-id ` attribute. updated my ans.